# `git submodule update` always keep fetching the same commit

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-fetch

I have a Git repo with one submodule and two commits that change the submodule's HEAD. If I check out one of the commits, and do a `git submodule update`, this succeeds without having to connect to a remote, as I would expect since I have the given commit available locally. If I check out the other commit, however, `git submodule update` always does a fetch (and fails if the remote is not accessible), even though it keeps re-fetching the same commit.

Example session:

```
$ git checkout -q 9089923 && git submodule update
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99'
$ git checkout -q 289a15d && git submodule update
From github.com:gergoerdi/chirp8-engine
 * branch            2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97'
$ git checkout -q 9089923 && git submodule update
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99'
$ git checkout -q 289a15d && git submodule update
From github.com:gergoerdi/chirp8-engine
 * branch            2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97'
$ git checkout -q 9089923 && git submodule update
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99'
$ git checkout -q 289a15d && git submodule update
From github.com:gergoerdi/chirp8-engine
 * branch            2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -> FETCH_HEAD
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97'
```

What is the reason for this, and how do I change it so that `git submodule update` doesn't keep re-fetching the same commit?

**Edited to add**

I started tracing `git`, and the difference all comes down to what `git submodule--helper` does:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99  -- chirp8-engine
11:08:30.962038 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 -- chirp8-engine
11:08:30.962259 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 --not --all
11:08:30.963983 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 --not --all
11:08:30.965639 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git checkout -q -f 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99
11:08:30.966504 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git checkout -q -f 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99'
```

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97  -- chirp8-engine 
11:08:35.917283 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -- chirp8-engine
11:08:35.917522 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 --not --all
11:08:35.919289 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git fetch
11:08:35.920134 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git fetch
11:08:35.920490 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: unset GIT_DIR GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''gergoerdi/chirp8-engine.git'\'''
11:08:38.965515 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
11:08:39.272774 run-command.c:1597      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
11:08:39.272791 run-command.c:1629      run_processes_parallel: done
11:08:39.272799 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
11:08:39.273925 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
11:08:39.274557 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 --not --all
11:08:39.276381 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git fetch origin 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97
11:08:39.277324 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git fetch origin 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97
11:08:39.277686 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: unset GIT_DIR GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''gergoerdi/chirp8-engine.git'\'''
11:08:42.446569 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
From github.com:gergoerdi/chirp8-engine
 * branch            2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -> FETCH_HEAD
11:08:42.754265 run-command.c:1597      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
11:08:42.754283 run-command.c:1629      run_processes_parallel: done
11:08:42.754295 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
11:08:42.755355 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
11:08:42.755976 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git checkout -q -f 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97
11:08:42.756942 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git checkout -q -f 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97
Submodule path 'chirp8-engine': checked out '2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97'
```

In particular, the trace diverges right at the start:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99  -- chirp8-engine
11:08:30.962038 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 -- chirp8-engine
11:08:30.962259 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 --not --all
11:08:30.963983 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 341b24f2c3168a6e226ae3c249179426eff6dd99 --not --all
```

vs

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97  -- chirp8-engine 
11:08:35.917283 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git submodule--helper run-update-procedure --oid 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 -- chirp8-engine
11:08:35.917522 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97 --not --all
11:08:35.919289 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git fetch
```

Indeed, there is a difference in the output of `cd chirp8-engine; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=.git git rev-list -n 1 $SUBMODULE_COMMIT --not --all` depending on which commit is checked out in the submodule, but that should be expected since `2fd6ace` is an ancestor of `341b24f`.

Answer (score 3):

`git submodule update` generally means this:

- get a list of submodules
- for each submodule:

  - find a commit hash ID: it's stored in the superproject's index, so run `git rev-parse :chirp8-engine` for instance;
  - `cd` into the submodule repository working tree;
  - run `git fetch` if necessary to *get* that commit; and
  - run `git switch --detach <hash>` to *check out* that commit.

That's what you're seeing here: this is how submodules are *supposed to work*.  It's the superproject, not the submodule, that "knows which commit to use".

With that in mind:

> `git submodule update` always does a fetch (and fails if the remote is not accessible), even though it keeps re-fetching the same commit.

The command could probably be smarter, but it's not.

There are ways to make it act differently:

- `git submodule update --no-fetch`: this tells it *never run `git fetch`*.  If you don't already have the commit you need, this makes the `git switch --detach` step fail, but it does avoid the `git fetch`.
- `git submodule update --remote`: this changes how the hash ID step (done first above) works.  Instead of using `git rev-parse :<path>` to read the hash ID from the superproject's index, Git will:

  - run `git fetch` *early* (unless suppressed by `--no-fetch` in which case there's no fetch at all); then
  - use `git rev-parse` *in the submodule* to obtain a hash ID, using a name constructed by pasting the remote name and a branch name together.  The result of this pasting-up is typically a remote-tracking name like `origin/somebranch` where `somebranch` is the name recorded in `submodule.<path>.branch`.

  The general idea behind this sequence is to obtain a possibly-never-seen-before hash ID, since `git fetch` might update some remote-tracking names.  Suppose that `submodule.foo.branch` is `develop`, and we run `git fetch origin` and get a new hash ID for `origin/develop` in the Git repository that holds the `foo` submodule.  We now run `git rev-parse origin/develop` within that submodule to get the hash ID.  So we'll now update to (or merge or rebase using) the resulting hash ID.
- `--checkout`, `--merge`, `--rebase`: these control what gets *done with* the hash ID once it's obtained.  The operation (`switch --detach`, `merge`, or `rebase`) happens *in the submodule repository* and *using the hash ID obtained by the obtain-hash-ID step*.

What I think you're asking for here is simply the `--no-fetch` option.  However, submodules are a big pain in the <insert body part>; making them work "as desired" is often very tricky, in part because we're often not even sure what "desired" means in the first place.  One way or another, we all discover, when we use submodules, why people call them *sob*-modules....

Comment: I understand perfectly fine that it's the superproject that knows which commit to use for the submodule. But what is different between the two states of either the super- or the sub-module that for one of them, a fetch is always done, and for the other, it is not?

Comment: I think this is the most relevant part of your answer: "run git fetch if necessary to *get* that commit" why do I keep not having commit `2fd6ace109f6337df97056aacdb40e5fb51f0e97`?

Comment: It's my opinion that the submodule code you're using is excessively stupid - it should just *check* first, and see that you do in fact have it, and skip the `git fetch` step. (However, if you are using `--remote`—not that you are—the fetch step is required. The stupid part is that if you're not, it should check first.) Note: The submodule helper code is being removed from Git and I'm not sure which versions have it and which don't, at this point.

Comment: I just upgraded to 2.39.0 which I believe has a new C implementation for `submodule--helper`, and that stlil fetches.

Comment: OK, so, that means it's still kind of dumb. You might want to smarten it up and submit that as a patch (though the Git project makes submitting patches painful).